# mobile phone and email field duplicate in account object

Tags: trigger, account

Hello Guys,
                I have wrote a trigger on account object that  whenever a user enter duplicate  phone number or email then it will show an error on page and the info will not stored in the account object.

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before insert, before update)
{
    //Account duplicate protection system.
    if (Trigger.isBefore && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate))
    {
        Map<String, Account> anAccountMap = new Map<String, Account>();
        for (Account anAccount : System.Trigger.new)
        {
            // Make sure we don't treat an mobile phone that  
            // isn't changing during an update as a duplicate.  
            if ((anAccount.Phone != null) && (Trigger.isInsert || 
                      (anAccount.Phone != Trigger.oldMap.get(anAccount.Id).Phone)))
            {
                // Make sure another new Account isn't also a duplicate  
                if (anAccountMap.containsKey(anAccount.Phone))
                {
                    anAccount.Phone.addError('Another new Account has the same mobile phone.');
                    System.debug('*** Error: found account with dublicate mobile phone: ' + anAccount);
                } else
                {
                    anAccountMap.put(anAccount.Phone, anAccount);
                }
            }
        }  
        // Using a single database query, find all the Accounts in  
        // the database that have the same mobile phone as any  
        // of the Accounts being inserted or updated.  
        for (Account aDBAccount : [SELECT Phone FROM Account WHERE Phone IN :anAccountMap.KeySet()])
        {
            Account newAccount = anAccountMap.get(aDBAccount.Phone);
            newAccount.Phone.addError('An Account with this mobile phone already exists.');
            System.debug('*** Error: found account with dublicate mobile phone: ' + newAccount);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:--** The thing is that its working but  its not showing any error on my particular page. Any help from the MVP's or the consultant  will be great.

Comment: Is this a visualforce page? If so, please include the page source.

Answer (score 0):

I checked this in

1. standard edit layout of Account
2. vf page of Account (standard controller)
3. Vf page of Account (custom Controller)

This code is working perfectly fine and giving error messsage properly at field level(phone)

Seems like some other issue in your page. did you check with

```
 '<apex:pageMessages />'
```

tag, if you're getting some other errors or not ?

Comment: @ curious_techy  yes i included this one also but nothing happen? actually i want to show the error message on the particular filed  on my customize  VF page  not the standard page.